# Convert string to be a valid to use in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have a little question for my json string. I have something like this:

```
[
    {
        "index": 0,
        "name": "block
        "    
        '
        "
    }
]
```

But its needs to be a valid json string with the new lines and these quotes. Is there somthing i can do in javascript to replace the string to make this json string

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse()` to convert an object to a JSON formatted string - however you first need to make what you have in to a valid object. At the moment it has some syntax issues.

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify()` to create a valid JSON string.

Comment: But can breaks and quotes be replaced by \n etc?

Comment: Why do you need those quotes?

Comment: for some text like I'm and i should delete the enters but i dont know how

Comment: This is not a valid javascript object. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: Sometimes will the quotes " will be used but then is my json string invalid

Comment: Ok I get the value of a textarea and I want the value of it but when the users uses breaks(enter) or quotes it will crash

Comment: then put validation on the textarea.  Do not manipulate the string. That is not the way to do it.

Comment: Paraphrase your question, please, it is not well understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It is from JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Look for more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse